# Space indent disappear when `o`/`O` follows by <Esc>

Tags: indentation

In short, I want to keep the indentation created by `o` after pressing `<Esc>`. To make it clear, I will try to describe my problem with an example.

Given the position of my cursor at:

```
function Test() {
  return (
    <div>█
    </div>
  )
}

NORMAL
```

When I press <kbd>o</kbd>:

```
function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      █                        // <-------- The state I want as result.
    </div>
  )
}

INSERT
```

Then if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
█                              // <-------- The space-indentation disappear.
    </div>
  )
}

NORMAL
```

Is there a option that I can set in my vimrc to control this behavior or do I have to write some vimscript by myself?

Comment: yes, type a letter and delete it directly again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need spaces on empty line. This is the reason Vim removes auto-indentation after Esc.

Whenever you're going to write something on empty line with indentation applied, you can press `cc` or `S`. Or you can re-indent text after you've finished with it (e.g. `==` or `='[` and so on).

Comment: Thank you, I will take the first option

Comment: `:help i_ctrl-t` is another option.

Comment: @romainl Yes, I used c-d/c-t for some time too. But they are really useful only if moving by lines in insert mode or if the auto-indentation is wrong. Neither of these two should happen often.

Comment: Here is my late check/accept. (believe it or not, I didn't know how great Vim is from the line `This is the reason Vim removes auto-indentation after Esc.` when I read your answer years ago.)

Answer (score 2):

You have `autoindent` on:

```
            *'autoindent'* *'ai'* *'noautoindent'* *'noai'*
'autoindent' 'ai'   boolean (default off)
            local to buffer
    Copy indent from current line when starting a new line (typing <CR>
    in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O" command).  If you do not
    type anything on the new line except <BS> or CTRL-D and then type
    <Esc>, CTRL-O or <CR>, the indent is deleted again.  Moving the cursor
    to another line has the same effect, unless the 'I' flag is included
    in 'cpoptions'.
```

As a workaround you can type something there, for example `space` and `backspace` which could be mapped as:

```
nnoremap o o<space><bs>
```